# How to flush data to database in Django with multiple processes? (or avoid caching)

Tags: python, django, background-task

I have a Django app that I've just started using `django-background-tasks` with, that collects a bunch of data from the user in a fairly complex form, and then pushes out parts of that data (processed) to other systems over the network. This can take a while, so I am using some new 'task' models, and a status page to keep the user informed, along with django-background-tasks to do the background work (which basically runs a worker as a management command).

So I have this:

```
class MasterTask(models.Model):
    installation = models.ForeignKey(Installation, related_name="push_tasks")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    date_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def completed(self):
        logger.info("Master Task %s Completed", self.id)
        self.date_completed = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
        self.complete = True
        self.save()

    def subtask_changed(self):
        if self.progress == 0:
            self.date_started = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)

        self.progress += 1
        logger.info("Master Task %s updated - serial %s", self.id, self.progress)
        self.save()

        if TaskItem.objects.filter(master_task=self).exclude(status='complete').count() == 0:
            self.completed()


class TaskItem(models.Model):
    master_task = models.ForeignKey(MasterTask, related_name="items")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="unknown")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    date_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)

    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def start(self):
        logger.info("Task Item %s Started", self.id)
        self.status = "started"
        self.date_started = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
        self.progress += 1
        self.save()
        logger.info("Task Item %s Started and saved", self.id)
        self.master_task.subtask_changed()
        logger.debug(self.status)

    def completed(self, results=""):
        logger.info("Task Item %s Completed", self.id)
        self.status = "complete"
        self.progress += 1
        if results != "":
            self.results = results
        self.date_completed = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
        self.save()

        self.master_task.subtask_changed()
```

and then in my 'submit' view, I create the master task which this user is interested in, and the various subtasks attached to that. Then launch the actual background task, which takes a dict including the ID of the subtask that it is related to, so it can update it. In there:

```
@background(schedule=1)
def push_to_device(task_info):
    logger.debug("Task starting for %s (item %s)", task_info['hostname'], task_info['taskitem'])
    taskitem = TaskItem.objects.get(id=task_info['taskitem'])
    taskitem.start()

    # ACTUAL WORK IN HERE

    taskitem.completed(results=results)

    logger.debug("Task done")
```

Now the problem - work proceeds as expected. Log entries appear as expected. However, the view that I leave the user with, which is a simple self-refreshing list of the subtasks and their current state, doesn't update as the subtasks run - it just jumps to all completed sometime after the end of a run. *EDIT So data **is** being saved to the database*

I assume that's because the view is running in the webserver, and the taskrunner in the command-line interpreter, and there is either some caching or internal change-tracking going on which means they don't see changes. How can I deal with that?

I'm considering switching to Celery, but I don't see that it would do anything differently for this particular problem.

**Update with more view detail**

The view is simply fetching the current master and subtasks:

```
def poststart_status(request, task_id):
    task_main = get_object_or_404(MasterTask, id=task_id)

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        "tasks": TaskItem.objects.filter(master_task=task_main),
        "master_task": task_main
    })

    return render(request, 'task-status.html', context)
```

And finally, the template, which is a simple iteration over the tasks list:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
(in the header block)


<h5>Master Task: {{ master_task }} ({{ master_task.progress }} - {{ master_task.complete|yesno:"Complete,In-Progress" }})</h5>

<p> Created: {{ master_task.date_created }}     Started: {{ master_task.date_started }}  Completed: {{ master_task.date_completed }} </p>

<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>    <th>ID</th>     <th>Seq</th>      <th>Status</th>     <th>hostname</th>        <th>results</th> </thead>
<tbody>
{% for task in tasks %}
    <tr><td>{{ task.id }}</td><td>{{ task.progress }}</td><td><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal task_{{ task.status }}"></em><span class="task_{{ task.status }}">{{ task.status }}</span></td><td>{{ task.hostname }}</td><td><pre>{{ task.results|truncatewords:10 }}</pre></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**More Update**

I replaced the work part of the background task with a 20-second sleep(). When a taskitem is in the started state (i.e. in the sleep), I can see in the debug logs that there was a database update to set that state - that is, I can see the SQL UPDATE - but it doesn't appear in the status view, even if I restart the webserver (using the devserver). The 'completed' state does actually reflect in the view as expected.

**Final (probably) Update**

I still don't know why this happened, but I have tried the exact same setup with Celery and it's not a problem there. As in, I changed the background-tasks decorator for the Celery one, and changed the function call to include .delay() which is the Celery way to do the same thing, and now I get the 'started' state as expected.

Comment: How are you polling the task status?  I'm not familiar with django-background-tasks, but does it update the task status in the database appropriately?  It may also help to post some snippets of your view.

Comment: django-background-tasks runs my task function. One of the parameters for that function (task_info) is a dict containing the database ID of the associated taskitem. So I fetch that model instance and have it update (which I can see happening in the logs).

The task status view is literally `TaskItem.objects.filter(master_task=this_master_task)` wrapped in a foreach loop in the template. It's showing the correct items, but not the current state. Which is why I'm thinking caching. My next step is going to be putting a long sleep in the background task, to see if I get the new or old state after.

Comment: Read up on [when are querysets evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).  Looping will evaluate the queryset of tasks.  You'll need to have your view refetch it from the database on each refresh

Comment: I do. I have a http-equiv refresh (currently - the aim is for something a little more sophisticated to update only the relevant parts of the page), which is reloading the view every 2 seconds. With that in one window, and the task-runner in another window, I'd expect to see a change in the view within 2 seconds of seeing the background task say it had started/finished.

Comment: I've added the template and view to the question. They are very simple.